# To what extend making one query to the database is better than making two?

Tags: database

**My problem:** I have to query the database to fetch a result of `crafts` and use `typehead` to find the best match.

I was having a conversation with my friend and he says: `You should query the database to fetch all the results and then loop through such query and perform your task.`

It got me thinking: `Right now it makes sense since I only have 7/8 crafts in my table. What is going to happen when the webaplication grows and I'll have 200/300/800 crafts?`

My question here is: **To what extend is better to query a DB a single time?** e.g. I'm using typehead to query the DB to get the `crafts`from the table `profissoes` and it has 8 crafts. Right now it makes sense to query one time and return all the `crafts`. What if my table has 800 records? 10000 records?
Does it make sense to query the DB once and get 800 records or query the DB every 3 characters pressed? How do you quantify such unit?

This is a *local* idea but it can be applied to anything using a DB.

Comment: There is no single answer here. It depends, that's the best you can get. Executing two separate queries against the database is going to incur the overhead of network traffic and talking to the database server twice. Is that going to be better than executing one query instead? Who knows, it depends on those two queries compared to that one query. **There is no silver bullet**.

Comment: Does it make sense to get **all** the records and filter on the client? Heck no. If that's your alternative to executing two queries, don't. Execute the two statements. (and yes, in many cases doing the first thing is going to perform better than the second, but if you're going to go with someones advice without looking at a specific scenario, aka "trust me I know what I'm doing", then at least don't do a table-scan)

Comment: In **any** case, the only viable solution in order to handle performance questions like this is this: Measure, measure, measure. Set up a real scale test system and perform real performance tests. This will tell you what is going to perform better *for your particular case*.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is exactly right. The important thing is to implement so that you can tune by changing access patterns without throwing away code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `Does it make sens to get all the records and filter on the client? Heck no.`does it apply to data that isn't that much *secret*? I asking this because in this case I'm just returning `crafts`. Publicly available.

Comment: If you got just a couple of records, talking about performance doesn't make much sense at all. If you consider 1000's of rows, then doing a table-scan (retrieving all the rows) is not a good idea. Period.

Comment: If you would like to post an answer I would accept it. You made it very clear